# X11 Frwarding Error while trying to run a Java Utility with GUI

Tags: java, unix, putty, x11-forwarding

I am trying to run a java utility on a UNIX Server through PuTTY. This JAVA utility launches a GUI. When I run this utility using the following command

```
./DAVTree.sh
```

I get the following Error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: 
    No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation 
    which requires it.

    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sas.services.webdav.tools.DAVTree.<init>(DAVTree.java:319)
    at com.sas.services.webdav.tools.DAVTree.main(DAVTree.java:944)
```

I searched on the internet for the problem its something called `X11 Forwarding` don't know what that is but I followed the suggestions by googling so I created a new session with PuTTY and under

`Connection > SSH > X11` checked yes the `Enable X11 Forwarding`

[image]

Now when I run the utility again the error\exception message has changed it now says.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window  

server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$100(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sas.services.webdav.tools.DAVTree.<init>(DAVTree.java:319)
at com.sas.services.webdav.tools.DAVTree.main(DAVTree.java:944)
```

Now it says that no DISPLAY variables is set. So I try this

```
export DISPLAY=kcsclm92:7001
```

kcsclm:7001 would be my server. After this when I run the utility it gives the same error only with the following difference

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window  

server using 'kcsclm92:7001' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

I was already working in blind after this I have nothing more to try. Please help.

p.s. (for those who know SAS)I have SAS deployment on a UNIX server and I am trying to run the DAVTree Utility.

Comment: Can you run non-Java applications? (Try `xterm` which is a simple terminal emulator that's almost certainly installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an X "server" running on your *local Windows machine*. (Yes, the terminology is confusing). Try http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/

Note, the correct DISPLAY setting will be created by Putty automatically, so don't change it (`localhost:10` sounds about right).

Comment: somebody should really build a Shell Script Tool which has an integrated XServer. you keep using PuTTY & SSH Secure Shell for years and one day they just disappoint you